# chaining builds in the TravisCI

Tags: github, travis-ci

Imagine situation like this on github:

- `repo 1`
- `repo 2` (has dependency to `repo 1` build artifact)

where both of these have travis configured.
However I'd like to run travis build of the `repo 2` also in the case of successful travis build on the `repo 1`.

Any chance/idea how to achieve that?

The only idea I had was to:

- create new user
- and in case of successful travis build of `repo 1` do `git` `commit` + `push` `repo 2`.

However that would lead to dirty commit history on `repo 2`. Well I could also remove all the new user's old commits, but that increases the complexity might be error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, It's not possible to do that right now, as you can only start a travis-ci build on a commit at the moment.

Obviously not ideal, but you can, however, in repo 2, clone git repo 1, run the repo 1 unit tests in repo 2, and if they fail stop the repo 2 unit tests from running and end the build.

Comment: well, the problem is that I need chaining here, rerunning the original tests in other repo is not an option for me

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Travis CI doesn't provide this feature. [There is feature request for it](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/249), but wasn't approved yet, so it's not even on roadmap so far.

This is reason why I switched to similar service: [drone.io](http://drone.io).
It's relatively new so some languages are in beta so far. Don't know if it is option for you.
It provides more features than Travis CI,

One of them is HTTPS hook for remote triggering the builds.
So you can configure repo1 Drone job to hit build hook of repo2.
This can be done via wget command (You need to wrap repo2 hook URL into double quotes).

Comment: Are you sure that drone.io is from Google?  From what I've read it look like an independent startup.

Comment: @shangxiao: you are right, it's not. i already realized that some time ago, but forgot to update my answer here. updated now. thanks